# How to create a mapping to replace all non word characters at the beginning of a line?

Tags: key-bindings

I'd like to quickly replace all non word characters up to first word `\w` character with a space.

```
----So that this line becomes
    So that this line becomes

----------------And this line looks like this
                And this line looks like this

--=======--^^---Likewise this becomes
                Likewise this becomes
```

This command: `0v\wr` (space after the r) works in normal mode, but when I place it in my `_vimrc` file, with `nnoremap <leader>! 0v\wr` (with space being the last character), I get stuck in visual mode without character replacement.

Comment: Use `<space>` instead of  an actual space.

Comment: That's a start, but I still get stuck in Visual mode without character replacement.

Comment: Well, how do you usually get out of visual mode?

Comment: When I'm in normal mode tying `0v\wr<space>`, the code performs as expected, I never need to escape visual mode as `r<space>` returns me to normal mode. When I add `<esc>` to the end of the `_vimrc` script, I get to operator pending mode.(Half size blinking cursor).

Comment: So, you just don't add the `<esc>` and problem was solved, right?

Comment: No,  If script ends in `r<space>` then executing the command from normal mode results in being in visual mode with no character replacement ever taking place. If script ends in `r<space><Esc>` then I end up with a half cursor, which I assume is operator pending mode, still no character substitution ever taking place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nnoremap <leader>! 0v<S-Right>hr<Space>
```

---

This possible solution may be also useful

```
:%s/^.\{-}\</\=repeat(' ',strlen(submatch(0)))/g
```

Read more

```
:h functions
:h function-list
```

Comment: Take my upvote for the use of repeat in the substitution, that's what I wanted to get to but couldn't remember or find how to do it! :-)

Comment: ryuichiro, You steered me in the right direction. The error was in using `\w` instead of just `w`. The `h` shifts my cursor to the left one position and won't replace  the one non-word character to the left of my word character. Both of the following work. `nnoremap <leader>!v<S-Right>wr<Space>` and `nnoremap <leader>!vwr<Space>`.  The latter is the original using `w` instead of `\w`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution which correct all the lines of your file in one command. *(Warning: might cause eye bleeding to regex masters)*

You can add these lines to your vimrc:

```
function! Test()
    let match = search('^\s*[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]\+\w')
    while match
        s/^\(\s*\)\(\W\)\(\w*\)/\1 \3/
        let match = search('^\s*[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]\+\w')
    endwhile
endfunction

nmap <Leader>! :call Test()<CR>
```

The function has a `while` loop which is true while a line begins by 0 or more whitespaces followed by a non word and non whitespace character followed by a word character.

Each time such a line is found the first non word character following a beginning whitespace is replaced by a whitespace.

And the mapping is here to call the function with <kbd>leabder</kbd>+<kbd>!</kbd>.

For the following file:

```
 ---So that this line becomes
----------------And this line looks like this
    =====--^^---Likewise this becomes
 -=======--^^---Likewise^^^^^ this becomes
```

You get:

```
    So that this line becomes
                And this line looks like this
                Likewise this becomes
                Likewise^^^^^ this becomes
```

That might not be the most elegant solution but you get the result :-)